# Как переделать header?

Tags: html, jquery, css, header

Чтобы "гамбургер" был внутри выпадающего меню, а само меню выпадало ниже шапки пикселей на 50?

```js
/***************** Slide-In Nav ******************/

$(window).load(function() {

 $('.nav_slide_button').click(function() {
  $('.pull').slideToggle();
 });

});


/***************** Nav Transformicon ******************/

document.querySelector("#nav-toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
 this.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
nav {
    background-color: #242830;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#nav-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -o-border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #353535;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
    top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
    top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    top: 10px;
}

.navicon {
    position: relative;
    height: 26px;
}

.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0 !important;
}

.pull {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <nav class="pull">
                            <ul class="top-nav">
                                <li><a href="#intro">Introduction <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#features">Features <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#responsive">Responsive Design <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#team">Team <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Get in Touch <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="hero" id="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 navicon">
                        <a id="nav-toggle" class="nav_slide_button" href="#"><span></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то типо того?

```js
/***************** Slide-In Nav ******************/

$(window).load(function() {

 $('.nav_slide_button').click(function() {
  $('.pull').slideToggle();
 });

});


/***************** Nav Transformicon ******************/

document.querySelector("#nav-toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
 this.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
nav {
    background-color: #242830;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#nav-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -o-border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #353535;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
    top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
    top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    top: 10px;
}

.navicon {
    position: relative;
    height: 26px;
}

.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0 !important;
}

.pull {
    display: none;
}


.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2.col-xs-8.col-xs-offset-2 {
    min-height: 40px;
    background: #242830;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after{
  background-color:white;
}
a#nav-toggle {
    position: relative;
    padding:20px;
}
nav.pull {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                    <a id="nav-toggle" class="nav_slide_button" href="#"><span></span></a>
                        <nav class="pull">
                            <ul class="top-nav">
                                <li><a href="#intro">Introduction <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#features">Features <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#responsive">Responsive Design <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#team">Team <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Get in Touch <span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav> 
    </header>
```

Comment: Да! Это то что нужно. 
Спасибо большое!